# How can I make custom (participant attendees) reports with inline editing functionality?

Tags: custom-fields, custom-reports

How can I make custom (participant attendees) reports with inline editing functionality?

**Larger Challenge/Background**

I want to create an overview for managing all attendees for (all future) events.

So far I have reports where Columns are names, ..., Participant-roles, Status, and some additional custom fields, such as: "leaves early", "age approved by staff".
The idea is, that our staff can - after people registerd for an event - manually check the attendees list. Sometimes a backup call is needed. This information should be then entered (dropdown) into the participant data. To save time and the annoying steps to go from the attendees list into each participant data, just to check off a marker or change the status e.g. from pending to attending, I want to do that inline.

I view those with reports. That works perfectly.

I looked into the extension "Extended Reports" (nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport). It claims to do that. And the predefined templates for Event and Activities are running and are working perfectly as intended! (basicly what is explained here: https://youtu.be/AyWwu7HoOkI?t=1732 at 28:52) I - however - cannot manage to make it available for a particapant attendees report.

**Specific Question**

- What am I missing?
- How can I make custom inline editing reports (with the Extended Reports extension)?

thx for the help, Stefan

---

I am running:

- Drupal 7.x
- CiviCRM 5.23.4 (could update though, just haven't done that yet)
- ExtendedReport (nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) version 5.1

Answer (score 1):

To clarify - the nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport extension offers Editable Reports for Activities and Events - but not for Participants.

Eg with the Events report you get fields like this

[image]

Another option would be to try Drupal Views and Views Bulk Operations. I am pretty sure we have made it work for an 'event register' ie have a list of folk who are Invitees, and then tick those who show up and VBO will change their Attendee Status (don't recall if we added the necessary so that the Status is a dropdown or you have to enter the status ID)

Comment: not out of the question we could add that feature but the work involved would need funding

Comment: thanks for the answer! and for the clarification! The feature would be awesome... the lack of funding though! :-(